# probability question about machine is used to generate codes consisting of 4 random characters

Tags: probability

[image]

Not sure on how to do part $e$.

I did $\frac{52}{62}\times \frac{25}{62}\times \frac{10}{62}\times \frac{9}{62} \times 4!$ but it didn't match the answer which is $0.0969$.

Comment: Don't use images of text or mathematics.  Instead, use Mathjax to typeset the content.  Also we require you to credit the original source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it in the form you tried, it will be

$\left(\frac{52}{62}\times \frac{51}{62}\right)\times \left(\frac{10}{62}\times \frac{9}{62}\right) \times \frac{4!}{2!2!}$

The first set of parentheses represent choosing , say $AB$ or $BA$, and the second set represents choosing, say, $35$ or $53$, and to prevent overcounting, in the last term, we need to divide $4!$  by $2!2!$

Comment: But if I can't pick the same type doesn't that mean I should minus 26 from the second letter

Comment: The question part (e) doesn't say you can't pick again from the same type, only  "two different letters" (with upper and lower case considered different) and "two different digits"

Comment: oh my god this entire time i read it as they are not different so I minus 26

Answer (score 0):

The numerator will be (C(52,2)*C(10,2)*4!) and denominator will be (26+26+10)^4.

Reason: Consider the code to be ----. Then imagine we first select what 2 different letters and what two different digits we will use, so total letters are 26+26 = 52, thus we select 2 out of 52 by C(52,2) and similarly digits and then arrange them in 4! ways since all are different. And denominator is all possibilities.

Second numerator should not be 25, read my answer to understand the complete reasoning.

Comment: ah i see but could you put it into the fraction format so I can see it better Im not too sure